# TCP doesn't send exact file

Tags: java, file, tcp

Okay, so i've been working on a lightweight TCP transfer application, it is almost complete, however, i've got a problem:
Whenever i try to send a file, it does get sent but when it arrives, it's always a couple of bytes bigger than the sent file. If i for example send a picture that's 111 093 bytes big, when it's received, it's 111 616 bytes big instead. (523 bytes bigger)

I am still able to open the image and such, but if i send and .EXE or .JAR, it'll give me errors when trying to launch because of these extra bytes.

These are my codes:

SENDER:

```
    public static void sendFileToServer(File file) {
    try {
        byteBuffer = new byte[1024];

        //PREPARING FOR TRANSFER
        output.writeObject("FILE:"+file.getName()+":" + byteBuffer.length);
        output.flush();

        Client.lblData.setText("Sending file...");

        //TRANSFERRING
        BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while ((fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }
        output.flush();
        fis.close();

        //TRANSFERRING
        output.writeObject("END");
        output.flush();

        Client.lblData.setText("File sent!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        Client.lblData.setText("Waiting...");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

RECIEVER:

```
if(file) {
try {
    message = (String) input.readObject();
    if(message.contains("END")) {
        Server.conLabel.setText("Connected to: " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName() + ":" + socket.getPort());
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    file = false;
    }
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {}

byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
int number;

while ((number = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fos.write(buffer,0,number);
}

} else {
    if (message.startsWith("FILE")) {
    //PREPARING FOR FILE TRANSFER
        file = true;

        Server.conLabel.setText("Recieving file...");

        for(int i = 0; i < Server.files.getSize(); i++) {
            if(Server.files.getElementAt(i).equals(message.split(":")[1])) {
            Server.list.setSelectedIndex(i);

            if(!new File(Server.dlLoc.getText()).exists()) {
            new File(Server.dlLoc.getText()).mkdirs();
            }
            if(!new File(Server.dlLoc.getText() + "/" + message.split(":")[1]).exists()) {
            new File(Server.dlLoc.getText() + "/" + message.split(":")[1]).createNewFile();
            }

            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Server.dlLoc.getText() + "/" + message.split(":")[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Also, this is the first time i've ever done something like this, so please tell me of other things that's useful in these codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

111,616 = 1024 * 109

You are writing complete buffers on the sender and not paying attention to the fact that the last buffer is short. Do this instead:

```
    int len;
    while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
```

Comment: Also, just a question, do you know how i would see how much of the file is transferred? (For a progressbar)

Comment: Determine the total file size before you start (using `java.io.File` methods), then keep a running sum total of (`len`) values and adjust the progress-bar as appropriate.